# Deleting unsent WhatsApp messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

What will happen if I do a "Delete for me" option to a WhatsApp message that doesn't have any ticks? Will it reach the recipient or will it be never sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

messages with no tick will not be delivered to the recipient as it is not moved from your device to server.

However if it have single tick that means it is delivered to server but still if you delete that message than it will be deleted from your device as well as from the server as it is not delivered to the recipient.

If message is delivered and have two ticks that it is delivered to the recipient and you have to delete that message for both to remove messages from both devices, but that is limited to some time frame, limited to 8 seconds i guess from the time it is delivered to the recipient device.